# Create npm React library including Sass files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, webpack, babeljs

I'm trying to create a React library. The components imports Sass files as follow:

```
import "./cp.scss";

class Cp extends Component {
    render() {...}
}
```

To do so i'm using babel to compile the library into es5 by adding the following script:

**package.json**

```
...
"scripts": {
  ...
  "compile": "babel -d lib/ src/" 
}
```

It works fine, i'm getting a component looking like that:

```
...
var Cp = function (_Component) {
...
exports.default = Cp;
```

excepted that Babel is not able to handle my Sass file. So when i try to import a component in another project i got the following error

```
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./cp.scss in ...
```

With webpack i manage to compile my library into a single js files. But i want to keep the files structure (like [material-ui](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui) do) so i can import components from others apps like `import {Cp} from 'library'`.

Is there a way to achieve the same library output using wepback or whatever to handle the Sass files ?

Comment: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader

Comment: You should write a webpack config with `sass-loader` and `babel-loader`

Comment: With webpack i manage to compile my library into a single js files. But i want to keep the files structure (like material-ui do) so i can import components from others apps.

Comment: I am guessing you are going to distribute your react library as an npm package. This way you can keep your library structure the same.

Comment: But if you want people to do something like  `import { Button, Form } from 'library'` then you should just export all of them from the index file.

Comment: It is the goal, but the library is written in es6 and includes Sass files.

Comment: @AlexandreAnnic I'm facing a similar challenge. Did you ever come to a solution?